# Smarty - PHP if / else

Tags: php, smarty

Hello I am using smarty and  trying to to get if / else working in tpl which display {$Code}

Php File

```
$this->_Smarty->assign("License_Key", TRUE);

$Value = '
License Key : 
{if $License_Key}
Valid
{else}
Not Valid
{/if}';

$this->_Smarty->assign("Code", $Value);
```

In Tpl File :

```
{$Code}
```

OutPut Is

```
License Key : 
{if $License_Key}
Valid
{else}
Not Valid
{/if}
```

OutPut should be :

```
License Key : Valid
```

Comment: You're assigning `$Value` like any other Smarty variable. At no point are you telling Smarty it's supposed to interpret that snippet as a Smarty template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to put content of `$Value` into .tpl file, not into PHP. So content of **.tpl** will be:

```
License Key : 
{if $License_Key}
   Valid
{else}
   Not Valid
{/if}
```

In **PHP**, assign only `$License_Key`:

```
$this->_Smarty->assign("License_Key", TRUE);
```

**EDIT:** But if you need to do it exactly how you write it, you can use [{eval}](http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/language.function.eval.tpl), try it like this:

```
{eval var=$Code}
```

But I still suggest you to use it with Smarty tags in Smarty templates, not in PHP files.

Comment: Yes , but i am looking for something else, so i have to use this way, is there any solution ? so i can use if/else which in assign

Comment: alright it worked fine, thank you very much, your the best :)

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you're looking for:

```
$Value = 'License Key : '.($License_Key) ? 'Valid' : 'Not Valid';
```

The `?` is basically if and the `:` is basically else.

Comment: This makes more sense than using smarty tags in PHP. That's not what it's designed for. Just do the condition in PHP like this and output result in smarty.